# i tried this sql request on python but is not working

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I have the following part of my code

```
 cursor.execute("select titre from article WHERE titre LIKE '%s%%' OR paragraphe LIKE '%s%%' " % (cherche, cherche)  )
```

the problem that the result is right just if the value of the parameter (cherche) is on the beginning of the sentences , but I want to have all result where paragraphe and titre contain the word (value of cherche).

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information, but I'm going to take a stab and say try: `cursor.execute("select titre from article WHERE titre LIKE '%%%s%%' OR paragraphe LIKE '%%%s%%' " % (cherche, cherche)  )`

Answer (score 1):

It might help to see what this string looks like after the values of `cherche` are substituted. There will not be a `%`wildcard before `cherche` such that the search only returns results which *start* with `cherche`. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) is a primer on SQL wildcards.

Then I have some unsollicited advise: **Do NOT use python formatting with SQL statements! Use the [`execute()` built-in substitution](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).** Otherwise you **will** suffer from [SQL injection](https://www.xkcd.com/327/), either by the hands of a cheecky user or because you supply a SQL statement yourself by accident.

Your code with sql-sanitizied format and hitting the keyword anywhere in the result:

```
sql = "select titre from article WHERE titre LIKE :key OR paragraphe LIKE :key "
cursor.execute(sql, key='%'+cherche+'%' )
```

Note that I use the `sqlalchemy` (and `oracle_cx`) colon-keyword-style syntax. The `sqlite3` module uses a questionmark for parameter substitution, and does not support keyword-style substitution.

Comment: thank you Sebastian for help, but actually it doesn't work , i try't with the following code and is working : cursor.execute("select titre,date_publication from article WHERE titre LIKE ? OR paragraphe LIKE ?", ('%'+cherche+'%', '%'+cherche+'%',))

Comment: That is an API aspect of the `sqlite3` module. `sqlite3` supports only `?` substitution afaik, while for example `sqlalchemy` (also sqlite compatible) uses `:key` for dict arguments and `:1` for non-keyword arguments. Fair point though, I'll update my answer.